# Jquery Focus on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML on the page has 20 `<input>` fields each named and given ID's in increasing order from 1 to 20.

If the variable `id` is set to the next sequential `id` (`id` + 1), this function will cause focus to apply to that field. However, when clicking outside of the current input field, the last one input field will not regain focus if the number entered is greater than 10, but an alert will be displayed.

```
$(":input").focusout(function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    var id    = $(this).attr('id');
    if(input > 10){ 
        alert('You must enter a number between 0 and 10 '+id);
        $("#"+id).select();
    }
});
```

How can the last input field be set to regain focus?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$("#"+id).select();
```

With:

```
$(this).focus();
```

In this case, `$("#"+id)` and `$(this)` are the same element, and I'm assuming you want to `focus` the element when there is an error.

Aside: I don't believe that `id` or `name` values can legally start with a number, you may want to prefix them with something like `option1`, `option2`, etc. It might work, but it might also cause issues later that are difficult to debug. Best to err on the side of caution and best practices.

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

**Edit**: After failing to get `focus()` to work, I tried with `setTimeout` and was able to make it happen. I'm not sure why, or if this is really necessary, but it seems to work.

```
$(":input").focusout(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        input = $this.val();

    if (input > 10){
        alert('You must enter a number between 0 and 10');
        setTimeout(function(){
        $this.focus();
        }, 1); 
    }
});
```

I'd love to hear if there is a better way to do this or an explanation. I suspect that the blur and focus events are not fired in an order that makes the previous method possible?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zRWV4/1/

As mentioned in the comments, you should eventually make sure the value is an integer with `parseInt` or similar (you seem to already be aware of this).

Comment: I've tried this. It seems to have the same problem. Cheers though

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to get `focus()` to work even outside the context of the function for some reason (at least on jsfiddle). I hope you find the solution, I'm at a loss for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your mentioning best practices too. It doesn't seem to have made it work, but thanks again

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. You have put alot of effort into this response. I am going to accept this answer. As it does resolve my issue. But like you I am intrigued to see if there is a better way to accomplish this. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yeah Max, I'm at a loss here.. it seems only FF5 needed the `setTimeout` call. Well, GL and see related new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046798/jquery-focus-fails-on-firefox

Comment: Cheers Wesley, Thanks for the link. I will be keeping an ear to the ground about this. Once again thanks for the solution.

Comment: When you apply setTimeout with a delay of 0 seconds, you can be sure that the code you put in the delayed function is executed after the main processing is finished. I guess the behaviour described in the question happens because the browser triggers focus on the next element after $this.focus() is ran. If you implement a focus-event writing something to console.log you'll see that two focus events are triggered when you leave an invalid field.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
$("#"+id).select();
```

by

```
$("#"+id).focus();
```

or even by

```
$(this).focus();
```

Comment: I've tried this. It seems to have the same problem. Cheers though

Answer (score 0):

(Try to use `.blur()` instead of `.focusout()`. But that probably won't help)

Try to remove the `alert()` for a while - it sometimes can make problems with focus...

Comment: it is firing already so I don't think this is the issue. I did change the script and try this though anyway. Thank you

Comment: @Max: ... I was afraid so... so try to remove the `alert()` for a while - it sometimes can make problems with focus...

Comment: Removed the alert, didn't seem to make any difference. I was able to click into another input and type away.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the text inside the input to compare it with a number. `var input = parseInt($(this).val());`
'

```
   $(":input").blur(function(){
        var input = parseInt($(this).val());
        var id    = $(this).attr('id');
        if(input > 10){ 
            alert('You must enter a number between 0 and 10 '+id);
            $("#"+id).select();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cheers for the advice. I tried your version to no avail. I will probably implement the parseInt though once I find out what is not allowing the focus to fire correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MadaraUchiha/YrNXW/2/)**

This is my code, I'll explain what I changed:

```
$('input[id^="input"]').focusout(function(){
    var selected = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (selected <= 10) {
        $("#input-"+selected).focus();
    }
    else {
        alert('Invalid Argument! 1-10 only!');
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

1. I use `focus()` instead of `select()` which won't work.
2. You confused `id` with `select` which caused you to always try and select `$("#input-IDOFSELECTIONINPUT")` instead of `$("#input-IDOFWANTEDINPUT")`
3. In your code, although an alert would have been thrown, the rest of the code would have continued normally. It won't in my code.
4. You've put your desired result (`$("#"+id).select();`) in the undesired condition (`input > 10`), which practically never gave it a chance.
5. Last but not least, I gave the inputs a better (and valid) id. IDs must not start with a number.

Comment: This demo seems to suffer from the same issues, it doesn't focus the field with the error.

Comment: It does for me. I recently updated it, so make sure you watch the updated version (/2/).

Comment: Still not working for me on FF5. Chrome is OK. Locked in `alert()` dialogs using IE8.

Comment: @WesleyM Works for me on Chrome. Let me try FF5.

Comment: @WesleyM Well I'll be... You're right, it doesn't work on FF, what a weird xbrowser inconsistency.

Comment: Just to clarify, IE8 was fine. Alerts just suck to debug with, I somehow triggered a loop. Yes, not sure what's up with the inconsistency, would love to hear an explanation. jsfiddle is dogging for me today too.

Comment: More testing is needed. Maybe filing a bug report to jQuery/Mozilla?

Comment: @WesleyMurch let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2429/discussion-between-rikudo-sennin-and-wesley-murch)

Comment: This example no longer exists.

Comment: Don't forget to use parseInt()

Comment: @julmot It's a 4 years old answer, but you're right :) Would you mind to suggest an edit?

Comment: @julmot Always use a radix parameter when using parseInt! Remember, `parseInt('010') === 8` in older browsers.