# How to set focus on input in modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to set focus on an input after the modal shows.

The solutions and links I've seen and tried so far: [How to focus on a form input text field on page load using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591910/how-to-focus-on-a-form-input-text-field-on-page-load-using-jquery), [Jquery Focus on input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046012/jquery-focus-on-input-field), and none of them works.

My code is actually pretty simple:

```
$input = $("#letter-change-text").find("input[type='text']");
$input.val($.trim("I am just testing!!"));
$("#letter-change-text").modal('show');
$input.focus(); // this should focus the textbox in order to allow immediately input by the user
```

You can check this issue in **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nce5aau8/)**.

I also have tried without any success:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $input.focus();
}, 0);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nce5aau8/1/

Comment: i think you have to wait until the animation finishes to focus the input. try increasing the wait time in the `setTimeout`

Comment: try getting the input after you show the modal - jqueryui might duplicate the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shown event

```
$(function(){
    $input = $("#letter-change-text").find("input[type='text']");
    $input.val($.trim("I am just testing!!"));
    $('#letter-change-text').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
       $input.focus();
    }).modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Well, I've just edited my post to that solution..but I will edit again and accept your answer.

Comment: Why do you edit a post to have the solution, that is what the answers are for....

Comment: can you explain what is 'shown.bs.modal' on 4th line?

Comment: @Amitkumar Read the bootstrap documentation. They fire events

Answer (score 0):

You can just try

```
$("#dgRejectSalvage").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('#RejectionReason').focus();
});
```